# Merr Doue, If be Eufel

Tags: password, steganography

You've been invited to a secret meeting of the Puzzlers (who cannot be named in person). Well, by invited, more sort of given the opportunity to be invited.

You were sent an email containing an image from the Puzzlers (who cannot be named in person). You've puzzled over it for weeks but still haven't been able to work it out. And now the guard is in front of you asking for the password.

The email said the password to get into the meeting was contained in the image. However it also says that you must prove yourself worthy by getting the password. So it seems it isn't as simple as you first thought.

[image: Merr doue if be eufel]

You approach the guard and say 'Merr doue if be Eufel'.

He smiles and shakes his head.

> Can you figure out the password to get into the Puzzler's meeting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Turning the image upside down and reading from right to left gives:
>
>  WELL DONE, IT BE 'ENTER'

Comment: This is correct, well done! That was quick

Comment: For me, the R, N, comma, and apostrophes gave it away.

Comment: @EngineerToast the comma and apostrophes were the clues. Bit too obvious?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I think the apostrophes gave it away more than the comma because they look so out of place upside down. The N could have just been a plain U and still looked like an N when flipped right-side up: $\bigcap$. I liked it, though. This is me trying to be helpful, not critical.

Comment: @EngineerToast, always open to advice or criticism, if it is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil For me the "rr" made it pretty obvious, because they don't really look like "rr" in the image.

Comment: Yeah I tried to make them look unsuspicious, guess i failed